# How to send a POST request using django?

Tags: python, django, urllib2

I dont want to use `html` file, but only with  django I have   to make  POST request.

Just like `urllib2` sends a `get` request.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Python 2, a combination of methods from `urllib2` and `urllib` will do the trick. Here is how I post data using the two:

```
post_data = [('name','Gladys'),]     # a sequence of two element tuples
result = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com', urllib.urlencode(post_data))
content = result.read()
```

[urlopen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) is a method you use for opening urls.
[urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) converts the arguments to percent-encoded string.

Answer (score 45):

Here's how you'd write the accepted answer's example using `python-requests`:

```
post_data = {'name': 'Gladys'}
response = requests.post('http://example.com', data=post_data)
content = response.content
```

Much more intuitive. See the [Quickstart](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/) for more simple examples.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing you should look at now:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: Url not working anymore, please share some examples when quoting a link.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use `urllib2` in django. After all, it's still python. To send a `POST` with `urllib2`, you can send the `data` parameter (taken from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)):

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
>
> [..] the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided

Answer (score 2):

**UPD 2024 (docs link was updated)**

Pay attention, that when you're using  `requests` , and make `POST` request passing your dictionary in `data` parameter like this:

```
payload = {'param1':1, 'param2':2}
r = request.post('https://domain.tld', data=payload)
```

you are passing parameters `form-encoded`.

If you want to send `POST` request with only JSON (most popular type in server-server integration) you need to provide a `str()` in `data` parameter. In case with JSON, you need to `import json` lib and make like this:

```
 payload = {'param1':1, 'param2':2}
 r = request.post('https://domain.tld', data=json.dumps(payload))`
```

documentation [is here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#more-complicated-post-requests)

OR:
just use `json` parameter with provided data in the `dict`

```
payload = {'param1':1, 'param2':2}
r = request.post('https://domain.tld', json=payload)`
```

Comment: how to import requests?

Comment: @watata `pip install requests` to get the package, and `import requests` in your program.