# Django built in request library?

Tags: django, django-1.11

I know untill a couple years ago Django did not have one, as there are several questions here regarding this topic but they are all atleast two years old

[How to send a POST request using django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308060/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-django)

They mostly recommend to use python-request or urllib

My question is, does Django contains this by default now? A module to make POST/GET requests to another server, or is there still need to install external libs?

This is mostly to avoid bypassing cross domain policies in using APIs

Comment: No, including such a library would be completely out of scope for Django.

Comment: Isn't Django scope web development? It already has so many tools that ease the flow of a web project

Comment: It is a web framework. It's used to develop the server application in the client-server architecture of HTTP. There's absolutely no reason to include HTTP client code in a server-side framework. It would only couple Django to a specific HTTP client implementation, rather than giving developers the option to choose whatever works for them in the few cases it's needed.

Comment: Django is a web framework, it's purpose it to receive requests and process them. I would suggest using the requests library. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django has no built in library for making HTTP requests. 
Most used python library for HTTP requests is `requests` which you found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests). It is simple to use, works well with Django. [Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) are docs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a django library called django-request library which is found in this doc [django request library](https://pypi.org/project/django-request/)